# How to interpolate variables in regular expressions in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to see if there is an entry for some input in a file, so I'm using a regular expression to query each line:

`cat $file | where {$_ -match "^script\$fileName -*"}`

where $fileName is some input defined elsewhere.

How do I alter the regex to interpolate the variable instead of matching for '$fileName' ?

Comment: I think it's because you escape `$`. Try leaving out the backslash. If you want to match a literal backslash, add a second backslash instead (to escape the backslash).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the answer given, as $fileName could contain characters such as '.' or '\' you should escape it as follows:

```
cat $file | where {$_ -match "^script\\$([regex]::Escape($fileName)) -*"}
```

The Escape method will escape bits like '.' and '\' for you.

E.g.

```
[regex]::Escape(".\bar.txt")
```

gives

```
\.\\bar\.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`$fileName` gets interpolated so you wind up with a string passed to regex that looks like this:

```
cat $file | where {$_ -match "^script\foo.txt -*"}
```

The `\` is acting as an escape character for the following character when in fact we want a liternal `\` to matched against.  In this case, you'll need to escape the escape character e.g.:

```
cat $file | where {$_ -match "^script\\$fileName -*"}
```

Comment: hi, \\ means \ in regular expression. so the first \ is escaping the second \ for regular expression. in powershell, ` is used for escaping instead of \, so $ is not escaped.

Comment: Yeah, we simply want the backslash escaped so that it can be used to match the path separator.  I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to break the RegEx up inside of powershell.

```
$fileName = 'test'
'^script\test-*' -match ('\^script\\' + $fileName + '-*')
```

More readable and will work with multidimensional arrays where variable has brackets `[]`

```
$fileName = New-Object object[][] 1
$fileName[0] = @('test')
'^script\test-*' -match ('\^script\\' + $fileName[0][0] + '-*')
```