# Use Variable in Replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file and want to regex/replace something with the content of a variable in PowerShell.

- File: `my.json`
- Variable in Powershell `$version`
- Search for: `version : "something"`
- Replace `"something"` with the **content** of the variable `$version`

Here is what I tried. Search and replace works as expected but the result is
`version : "$version"`.

```
(Get-Content my.json) -replace '(?<pre>"version"[\s]*:[\s]*)(?<V>"[^\"]*")', '$1"$version"' | Out-File my.json
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13286724/2486496) answer help at all?  I think an escape sequence should alleviate your issue, either way.

Comment: Powershell has natively implements a JSON parser, you'd better use that if you can. Check out the [ConvertFrom-JSON](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh849898.aspx) and [ConvertTo-JSON](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh849922.aspx) methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use variables in the replacement string you need to use a double-quoted replacement string, meaning that you need to escape backreferences and nested double quotes:

```
(Get-Content my.json) -replace '...', "`$1`"$version`"" | ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit! Have a great day!

Comment: @dknaack if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 2):

Ansgar's answer is perfectly valid, but `` ` `` escape sequences can be ugly and hinder readability.

I would personally use the `-f` format operator to concatenate the `'$1'` string literal and the value of `$version`:

```
(Get-Content my.json) -replace '...',('$1{0}' -f $version)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks better, yes